# JQuery: get ID,Value of all Input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm tryng to get all the ID,value of each input element on 'page-templete1'
and i didn't succeed

```
function Temp1() {          

var input = [];

$('page-templete1 input[name][id][value]').each(function(){


input.push(this);
cc=$(this).attr('id'));
 alert(cc); // trying to get one at time (not working)});
alert(input[0].id); // not working

alert(input[0].attr('id')); // not working

});

alert(input[0].id); // not working

alert(input[0].attr('id')); // not working
```

}

how can I get ID,value of all Input elements in a page and have access one them later
note: I done know the IDs of the input elements  or how many. there is an old post talking about similar problem but didn't solve my problem

Comment: try removing the `[name][id][value]`at from the selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on whether your "page" is an id you may need the dot or hash before the selector:

```
var results = [];
$('#page-templete1 input').each(function(){
    results.push({
        id: this.id,
        value: this.value
    });
});
```

Comment: If you want to send result as model to controller, you should try replace
`id: this.id,`
to
`name: this.id,`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code :

```
  $(function(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'))
    })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = [];
$('page-templete1 input').each(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id'),
        val = $(this).val();
    alert("id: " + id + " with value: "+ val);
    inputs.push({id:id, value:val});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an array to a variable: `var inputs = [];` and then try to read the array by referencing an undefined variable: `input.push(this);` (using `input` instead of `inputs`).

Answer (score 0):

serializeArray will help you
try this:

```
var array = jQuery('your input selector').serializeArray();
```

the result will be

```
array{{name="", value=""})
```

to access try this

```
var array = jQuery('input').serializeArray();
array.each(function(obj){
    //do what with your object
});
```

Comment: what "array" structue and how can I access the elements is it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery input selector and iterate over it.

Try something like this

```
        $(function(){
             jQuery( "#pageTemplate :input" ).each(function(){
                var id = this.id;       // for id
                var value = this.value; // for value
            })
        })
```

Note : you have to specify whether your page-templete1 is id or class